# VPN WIFI Device to SonicWall TZ500

Tags: vpn

I want to know if it is possible to purchase some kind of device that acts as a wifi router, but connects to the SonicWall via VPN?   The Wifi device will have to be inside the DMZ of another network, so site to site will not work, but I am hoping that somehow some sort of device can be configured to connect to the VPN as a VPN Client to the SonicWall, and what would I need to do to do so?  I tried OpenVPN, but was not having any luck.

Bottom line, I want to be able to go travel somewhere, plug this device in a hotel room eithernet port, and then automatically have WIFI that is part of my SonicWall's subnet.

Comment: Any router / WiFi combo unit with built-in VPN capabilities should work. If you can connect to the VPN from different locations with a computer, you can also certainly plugin a router to build that tunnel as well so that all devices that connect behind it are on the VPN. We don’t do hardware recommendations here, but there are affordable and highly capable units from the likes of Zyxel or Mikrotik. I’m curious though, being it’s a single, traveling computer why wouldn’t you just install a VPN client on the computer?

Comment: Thanks, the reason why is so that all devices can be on the vpn at a time, using the same SSID as we are use to using.

Comment: I may not be understanding your request properly. You said when you travel you want to plugin to a hotel. Are you traveling with an entourage of devices? Typically you would just connect to the hotel WiFi and connect the VPN client on your laptop.

Comment: This is what I needed to do: https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505253857071

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your help, I was able to figure it out this way: https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/170505253857071